# Correctly disposing of curves in THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I have a sphere with multiple moving points on it, and I am drawing curves connecting the points like this:

[image: Curves]

Since the points are moving, I draw these curves for every frame, and thus there is a lot of memory overhead that I am worried about.

Each curve is drawn with

```js
// points = array of Three.Vector3 size 40
path = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points)
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( 
                      new THREE.TubeGeometry(path,64,0.5,false), // geometry
                      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff}) // material
                     ) 
scene.add(mesh)
```

and for disposal:

```js
scene.remove(mesh)
mesh.material.dispose()
mesh.geometry.dispose()
```

It **does not** let me, however, dispose of my array of *40 Three.js vectors* `points` and of my *CatmullRomCurve3* `path`.

What is the issue, and how do I dispose of the `new THREE.Vector3()` and `new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the issue, and how do I dispose of the new THREE.Vector3() and new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3().

`dispose()` methods in `three.js` are mainly intended to free GPU memory which is associated with JS objects like geometries, materials, textures or render targets. Instantiating curves and plain math entities like `Vector3` do not cause an allocation of GPU memory.

Hence, it should be sufficient to just remove any references to `path` so it can be cleaned up by the GC.

Comment: Oh, makes sense! Thank you so much!